# Link opens as part of page PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have problem with simple link function. On submission form, there is textbox where user can include url. This url is then taken and changed into working link and placed in post. This part works fine. If user include http/https in front of url it will work fine. But if they don't include **http/https** or only **www**, then it will open link as example below:

1. mysiteexample.com/UrlTheyPasted.com
2. mysiteexample.com/www.UrlTheyPasted.com

(This should open as link to Video/Image/Site,..)

Here is code:

```
$output .= '<DIV CLASS="'.$outerclass.'">';
$output .= '<DIV CLASS="'.$innertclass.'">'.$title.'</DIV>';
$output .= '<DIV CLASS="'.$innervclass.'"><a href="'.$value.'" target="_blank">'.$value.'</a></DIV>';
$output .= '</DIV>';
```

Anyone know solution for this or why is this happening?

Comment: if you are indicating you originally took the value from the user as input...please share the php code that is processing that variable.  that is where you will need to take action, although, i supposed you could do it after the fact and the code will be similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the processing of the user input, use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) to find out if they have put the protocol on or not and act accordingly.

```
$url = 'test.com';
$urlscheme = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
if (empty($urlscheme)) {
  $url = 'http://'.$url;
}
die('<pre>'.print_r($url,true));
```

so for instance, just before your code, put the example:

```
$scheme = parse_url($value, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
if (empty($scheme)) $value = 'http://'.$value;

$output .= '<DIV CLASS="'.$outerclass.'">';
$output .= '<DIV CLASS="'.$innertclass.'">'.$title.'</DIV>';
$output .= '<DIV CLASS="'.$innervclass.'"><a href="'.$value.'" target="_blank">'.$value.'</a></DIV>';
$output .= '</DIV>';
```